# PowerPoint won't let me edit a text box within a template

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentation-design, microsoft-office

I'm having an issue with [this template](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.uibk.ac.at%2Fmedia%2Ffiler_public%2F89%2Fb8%2F89b8c1e8-27a5-4452-b7cf-07bb7dba9c41%2F02_pp_1_vorlage_16zu9_deen_2023.pptx&wdOrigin=BROWSELINK) for PowerPoint and need some assistance. I'm currently using the slides containing the text "Zitat bearbeiten" (slide 11) and the one with two columns and separate headers containing the text "Untertitelformat bearbeiten" (slides 7 and 8).

I am unable to edit the text inside the quotation marks. It seems to have no indicators of being able to edit or being part of a background element. Is there a way to change or edit this text within these templates?

I'm unsure if this problem is related to the PowerPoint version I am using, as I am on the latest version (365).

Answer (score 1):

The objects you can't change are parts of a particular layout that were not created as a placeholder. To be able to edit it, you could either change it into a placeholder or edit the layout directly. To do that (depending on your Office version), you need to go to the 'Slide Master', as officially instructed [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-and-re-apply-a-slide-layout-6f4338f8-555f-49cf-9835-6209be3c7b48). Since you're using a newer version, you will have to find it through the ribbon at the top of the window, i.e. `View` -> `Slide Master` (under the Master Views category).

You should now be able to edit the text of the object. Alternatively, if you want it to be editable outside the Slide Master you would need to [add a new placeholder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-edit-or-remove-a-placeholder-on-a-slide-layout-a8d93d28-66cb-43fd-9f9d-e12d0a7a1f06) and remove the existing one as changing the object directly to a placeholder isn't currently possible as far as I know. This can be done by clicking on `Insert Placeholder` on the Slide Master ribbon, and [using the Format Painter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-format-painter-4bb415a9-d4e4-42b7-b579-170adc594e40) to copy the style into the new placeholder. Afterwards, you may have to resize it accordingly, and finally delete the previous one.